# Eclipse SWT List background changes outside IDE's environment

Tags: java, eclipse, list, swt, kde-plasma

I've built my java application using org.eclipse.swt and now Im having a little big problem.

I need a custom background for a `List` widget and I set it. It works perfectly... inside eclipse. If I export my jar and run my application it loads the system default behaviour for lists (NOTICE other components such as `Label`, `StyledText`, ... preserve my custom background with no problems), which consists in alternate white and light-gray colours for each element (this was tested under KDE).

I have this problem with `Combo` widgets too, but other components I've used work perfectly.

Any idea about how can I fix this?

Snippet:

```
list = new List(composite, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
list.setBackgroundImage(null);
list.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_RED));
list.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(255, 215, 0));
```

Comment: Note that for some widgets on some platforms, the background color canot be set (From the JavaDoc: This operation is a hint and may be overridden by the platform). Does the exported application also run on KDE?

Comment: Yes. Iam running in the same machine both of them. Into the same system inside eclipse works OK but outside it's background got override.

Comment: Can you ensure that the same SWT version is used in both cases? If you build a minimal SWT application (a `Shell` with a background-colored `List`, no more), can you see the same behavior (integrated launch works, exported version does not)?

Comment: I tried to do a simple shell with a List.
Occurred exactly the same.

Snippet:

    public TestWindow(Display display) {
        super(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
        List list = new List(this, SWT.BORDER);
        list.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
        list.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_YELLOW));
        list.setItems(new String[] {"TestItem1 ", "TestItem2", "TestItem3"});
        list.setBounds(10, 10, 221, 181);
        createContents();
    }